# Access log4j2 map lookup in a custom lookup plugin

Tags: plugins, log4j2

I have a custom lookup plugin that needs to access a value from the standard map plugin (map:contextName) to do further processing.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm only interested in the context name I found that I could just do:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
String contextName = ctx.getName();
```